# How Can I Get The Email Sender Address

Tags: c#, email, email-client, reply

I'm developing a email manager application(like outlook) in C# and I want to do a reply function, but how I can get the email address of the user that sent the email that will be replyed? Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to access the email object?

Comment: It's a console application, it's only for personal use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage receivedMessage = GetMail();
string replyTo = receivedMessage.From;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are parsing the message you are replying to, but the information you are looking for is part of the e-mail headers. Generally there will be a Reply-to header, with the e-mail address you should sent any replies to.